# Stuttering on all games. The more demanding, the more stuttering it seems

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Problem:

Stuttering in all games. The stuttering is pretty bad. It's not like a micro stutter or one of those input lag things that only a competitive/attuned player would notice. This is very, very noticeable stuttering. Like freezing for 1/4 of a second. There is no tearing, just random points where the FPS is probably something like 2-5 for a quarter of a second. When this occurs, it lasts for about 2-5 seconds. It occurs in heavier games more often, and in older games like TF2, it occurs when the action ramps up.

This happened recently. The gaming rig was working excellent, but now nothing works quite right at all. I tried updating to an older version of graphics driver (since this seems to coincide with the newer release coming out and that didn't fix it).

Specs:

- CPU: i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
- RAM: 8GB
- OS: Windows 8.1, latest patches. 64-bit
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 760, driver 340.52
- OS + apps like browsers, steam are installed on an SASD. All games are all installed on an HDD.
- Resolution: typical 1080 at full screen.
- PSU: 750 Watt

Games stuttering: tf2, bioshock infinite... probably all as well.

I tried:

- Rebooting
- Switched to a new PSU I had laying around.
- Try messing around with vysync
- Turned off Windows Defender real time monitoring.

My only thoughts on what to do next:

Reinstall Windows 8.1. I tried playing with vsync and related settings in Nvidia Control Panel and that kind of helped make it smoother, but it would still slow down a lot instead of stuttering. it basically made the stuttering turn into a smoother slow-down, which clearly is pointless as nothing has been fixed and the problem is still bad.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows will not solve this problem there is something else going on if your FPS is going down to 2-3 my guess your actually using the Intel GPU we need a dxdiag report I have the 770 and the same cPU btw

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The FPS never is reported from FRAPS is going down to 2-3. Probably because it is just not that accurate. But I am just describing the nature of the stuttering. It clearly is freezing up, and in that quarter or eighth of a second, very few frames are rendering. I ran dxdiag and it shows that my Dispay chip is the GeForce GTX 760

Comment: Want to see the log for myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue awhile ago. It was that the heatsink wasn't mounted tightly, and after moving the computer, it basically unpried itself slighty.

Solution: re-tighten the heatsink. It needed to be "pushed" in on the 4 plastic bolts until each one clicked.